# jQuery height function not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've run into issue with jQuery, when I set the height of a div to window height, using the code at [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/cetofet/edit?html,css,js,output), it works, but then when I reduce the window height by manually reducing size of my browser, it gets chopped off, the extra portion of the div goes out of screen.

I set it up on [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/cetofet/edit?html,css,js,output)
If you resize the browser window, you will notice that list number 3 (and so on) will be out of the screen. I can't wrap my head around why it happens, I've tried changing jQuery version, I've <strike>double</strike> triple checked the code, I can't find anything wrong with it. I've rewritten it too, still not working. I searched on another forum, they told me to add a jQuery resize function, and that proved to me that they hadn't even took a look at my code, because I already have that function, but it's like the setHeight function is not being executed on window resize. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need any scripts to achieve what you want. Heres only css solution - https://jsbin.com/xopamakiru/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Your navbar is `position: fixed` it positioned relative to the `body`, so you can simply add `height: 100%` and it will take whole height of viewport. You need to add same height to children elements so they will be 100% height of nav bar. You have 3 `li` elements (100% / 3 = ~33.33%), so adding `height: 33.33%` to it makes them equal height. Because of we are using percents, element's heights resize automatically when user resizes window.

Comment: Well, I have included it into my actual project. But still, with the link you provided, even then, try resizing your browser window, it still doesn't resize the div to fit in all three links.

Comment: Oh, that's great, thanks it worked. Do you mind explaining that?

Comment: I was going to put the same answer :)

Comment: @msamprz It just how css works, add some explanation to the answer

Comment: Great. Thanks. I appreciate it.

Comment: @t1m0n Hi, sorry, I tried the same thing you explained with another div [here](https://jsbin.com/hulozu/edit?html,css,output), but it didn't work. I'm really at the point of pulling my hair because a simple div height has kept me from progressing through my work so much.
**edit:** I forgot to mention the problem, but it's the same thing, when I resize browser window, the words go out of screen.

Comment: @msamprz it works correctly, you have `width: 45%`, and your block will not become wider than that. Text will try to fit this width and if it can't it will go to another line and so on, below the screen, its how things work. I advise you to read css basics, e.g. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527334.do In your case you should change width of your black div when its content become higher than viewport, and it can be done only with js.

Comment: @t1m0n I see, thanks. That makes sense. And sure, I'll read into that.